# How do I read a 16 bit .wav audio file into a buffer suitable for writing to an Android AudioTrack?

Tags: android, audio

Is there a replacement somewhere in the SDK for javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat and associated stuff that allows you to open a .wav file and extract the PCM samples from it? Or do I really need to implement my own codec?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [OpelSL ES](https://www.khronos.org/registry/sles/specs/OpenSL_ES_Specification_1.0.1.pdf) ( programming in native code ). You can do audio manipulation that you want and it is very recommended for audio processing.